# Using servlet form on jsp page without redirecting to servlet

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets, jstl

I'm working on a project that requires a JSP page which includes another JSP page that processes a login form using a Servlet.

The problem I am coming upon is that whenever I try to login, the servlet works, the possible mistakes in the form show up, but the link redirects to the Servlet and does not stay on the same JSP page.

Example of how it looks with a template:
-JSP Page before clicking login

link: JSPpage.jsp

```
**text outside of included login form**
<included JSP page with the login form>
Email: something
Password: ******
```

-JSP Page after clicking login

link: MyServlet

```
<login form>
Email: something
Error: invalid email
Password:
```

Basically the highlighted text that is outside of the included form disappears. That is because the link changed to Servlet.

I want to process the login from inside the JSP Page, so that any template around the login form will remain the same and will not get deleted (the page won't redirect).

I've searched all over for a solution to this problem.
I realize that my explanation is really weak & I apologize for that.

Please be so kind and help me with this. I do not wish to use AJAX or JavaScript or a frame to do that unless it's a MUST and can't be done with JSP/Servlet directly.

Thank you,
Matej.

**EDIT:**
Servlet: Prijava.java

```
package servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import baza.Podatki;



public class Prijava extends HttpServlet{



  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
  {
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        String email=request.getParameter("email");
        String geslo=request.getParameter("geslo");

        int st=0;
        if (email!=null){
            try {               
                if(!Podatki.shranjenEmail(email))
                    request.setAttribute("napakaPrijava", "Email ne obstaja!");
                else if (!Podatki.preveriPrijavoUporabnik(email, geslo)&&!Podatki.preveriPrijavoZaposlen(email, geslo))
                    request.setAttribute("napakaPrijava", "Nepravilno geslo!");
                else{
                    request.setAttribute("prijava",true);
                    session.setAttribute("email", email);
                }
                request.setAttribute("email", email);               
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else if (request.getParameter("odjava")!=null)
            session.removeAttribute("email");
        System.out.println(session.getAttribute("email"));
        System.out.println("Prijava:"+request.getParameter("prijava"));

        RequestDispatcher view = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Prijava.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);

  }
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
      doPost(request,response);
  }


}
```

Prijava.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
     <%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Renta Ferari</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="obrazci.css">
    </head>
    <body >
    <div style="width:250px;height:110px; border:solid 1px; bordor-radius:15px; border-color:red">
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${!prijava}">
                <form method="post">
                    <table align="center">
                        <tr><td>E-mail:</td> <td><input type="text" name="email" class="vnos" value="${email}"></td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Geslo: </td><td><input type="password" name="geslo" class="vnos"><br></td></tr>
                        <tr><td colspan="4"><c:out value="${napakaPrijava}"></c:out></td></tr>
                        <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="prijava" value="Prijava"></td></tr>
                    </table>

                </form>

            </c:when>


            <c:otherwise>
                <div align="center">
                    Prijavljeni ste kot: <c:out value="${email}"></c:out>
                    <form method="post" action="login">
                        <input type="submit" name="odjava" value="Odjava">                  
                    </form>
                </div>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>

        </div>




    </body>
</html>
```

So basically I want to include the above code inside a new JSP along with my template's header, content & footer.

I tried many options and "solutions" like jsp:include, <%@ include file .. etc. None worked as I wanted them to. Whenever I clicked on the submit button for the login, it redirected me to the servlet's URL, thus overwriting the included header, content & footer.

I am not asking for you to code it, I'd just like some insight on how I can do this, since many websites do that.

Comment: Can you show the code in your servlet and JSF files?

Comment: I've added the code accordingly, I hope I explained it well also. @helderdarocha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what your code and what you say, it sounds like you have a login form included on each page of your application. When the user uses the form you want them to be redirected back to whatever page they were viewing before submitting the login form.
What you could do is include servlet path of the orginal servlet or jsp as a hidden field in your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="forwardTo" value="${pageContext.request.servletPath}" />
```

Then you can forward to this in your Servlet:

```
String forwardTo= request.getParameter("forwardTo");
RequestDispatcher view = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(forwardTo);
    view.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: I have tried it, getting HTTP Status 500 - Null pointer exception and redirecting to the servlet page